# Magento -> extend Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc : how I return that the payment was successful or declined

Tags: php, api, magento, payment, checkout

I wrote a credit card payment module in Magento .. With debugging, all the transactions that are done works, everything works, but I still can't return to Magento if the payment was successful or declined ..

i have capture and authorize, both are allowed and return "`$this`".

At the beginning of "capture", i run the "authorize" method (because authorize seems to not be automatically called when i use `<payment_action>authorize_capture</payment_action>` in the config.xml .. Everything works nice (API calling, authorization and capture), but when all the operations are correctly finished, OnePage Checkout return nothing, its stay on the last checkout page and do nothing, like i didn't pressed the "Place order" button.

So the question is : How do i return to Magento that the transaction (capture and/or authorize) was successful inside my class that extend "`Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc`" ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If your coding efforts are prefect then you can check whether the transaction is complete or not by reading out the Quotes given in each orders.

You can locate it in admin,
`Admin->Sales->Transaction` also transactions with order status, `Admin->Sales->Orders.`

In Magento, easy to trace an error is by setting a log. To avoid and identify errors its better set a log and view where you have mistaken. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. I already checked all the logs, and there's nothing. Admin->Sales->Transaction had recorded no transactions actually ..